# React array being returned with no data, but there is data within the array with inspect element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating an array of objects in react which contain a name and colour (the colour is for the colour of the pointer on google maps). These objects look like this `{ name: "Ben", colour: "green" }`.

The issue I am facing is when I run this code. For example, in my javascript file, I have this bit of code:

```
data.forEach((element) => {
  if (!names.has(element.person)) {
    names.add(element.person)
    keys.push({ name:element.person, colour:element.personColour })
  }
})
```

This loops through my data, which in this case are photos, and pulls out the name and a corresponding colour for that person. There are checks to ensure the person isn't a duplicate, also. At the top of the file, I define `keys` and `names`, `keys` as an array, and `names` as a set.

If I type a `console.log()` statement at the bottom of this code to print keys, the data is displayed in the console.

However, when I go to my react return statement to return my JSX, and I type `{console.log(keys)}`, I am returned this:

```
[]
--> 0: {name: 'Ben', colour: 'yellow'}
    1: {name: 'George', colour: 'pink'}
    2: {name: 'Jerry', colour: 'green'}
    3: {name: 'Jesus', colour: 'orange'}
    4: {name: 'Max', colour: 'purple'}
    5: {name: 'Tom', colour: 'blue'}
    length: 6
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

As you can see, I am shown an empty array, but with data inside, I cannot access it. I have tried to make it a promise and then resolve it, but I am returned a blank array.

I am fairly new to JS and React, so that any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: can you show the full component?

Comment: What is this?  The syntax isn't valid.  Can you correct your question text please?  `{console.log(keys}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it could be that data didn't finish downloading, you get the data in a useEffect than u do whatever u want with it

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
   setData(your fetched data method here)
}, []) //[] <-on page render

function x() {
   data.forEach((element) => {
      if (!names.has(element.person)) {
         names.add(element.person)
         keys.push({ name:element.person, colour:element.personColour })
      }
   })
}
```